# Find value based on a combination of columns

Tags: python, pandas

**Is there a way to find a value based on the combination of column values?**

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'One' : [np.random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(10)],
    'Two' : [np.random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(10)],
    'Three' : [np.random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(10)],
    'Four' : [np.random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(10)],
})
```

.

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   One  Two  Three  Four
0    8    1      7     5
1    6    3      3     3
2    4    7      5     2
3    4    2      6     9
4    1    7      1     9
5    9    8      3     8
6    4    8      4     4
7    1    9      7     1
8    4    2      6     4
9    1    3      7     7
```

I have the following df and I'm interested which of the columns would I need to combine to get number 9. This would be a column based combination, so each row would output a name of columns that were combined to find 9.

- In example row 0 will be give the result: `['One', 'Two']`
- row 1: will give a combination of `'One'` and all other three.
  `['One', 'Two'], ['One', 'Three'], ['One', 'Four']`
- row 2: False
- row 3: ['Four']

and etc...

**NOTE: DataFrame should stay immutabile.**

Thanks for any future suggestions or help.

Comment: By 'combine' do you mean 'any combination of columns in this row can be summed to make 24'?

Comment: @JeffUK yes, basically .sum() == 24

Comment: Is it Any combination of Any columns or is is sum of ALL columns = 24?

Comment: Any combination of Any colum. I will change the example so it is a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get all the combinations of column names for the dataframe, you can use `itertools.combinations` for it, then create a function that will calculate the `sum` for each of the combination of column names, and store such combinations in temporary list if the `sum` equals the required sum, finally return the list of column combinations, and apply this function on dataframe, for `axis=1`

```py
import itertools
cols = [j for i in [[list(col)
                     for col in (itertools.combinations(df.columns, i))]
                    for i in range(1, df.shape[1] + 1)]
        for j in i]
def getSubArray(row, sum_=9):
    result=[]
    for col in cols:
        if row.loc[col].sum()==sum_:
            result.append(col)
    return result 
result = df.apply(getSubArray, axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
0                                                   [[One, Two]]
1    [[One, Two], [One, Three], [One, Four], [Two, Three, Four]]
2                                    [[One, Three], [Two, Four]]
3                                                       [[Four]]
4                                    [[Four], [One, Two, Three]]
5                                                        [[One]]
6                                                             []
7                                    [[Two], [One, Three, Four]]
8                                                             []
9                                                             []
dtype: object
```

You can pass any value for required sum to `getSubArray` from `.apply` call, like: `df.apply(getSubArray, axis=1, sum_=24)`

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import combinations
def find_9(x, v=9):
    c = combinations(x.index, 2)
    columns = []
    for i,j in c:
        if (x[i]+x[j]) == v:
            columns.append([i,j])
    return columns if columns else False

df.apply(lambda x: find_9(x),axis= 1)
```

ouput:

```
0                               [[One, Two]]
1    [[One, Two], [One, Three], [One, Four]]
2                [[One, Three], [Two, Four]]
3                                      False
4                                      False
5                                      False
6                                      False
7                                      False
8                                      False
9                                      False
```